# recover partially overwritten tape from tar -c

Tags: tar, data-recovery, tape

I have a situation. I was supposed to run tar -x to recover a tar file from a tape but I pressed "c" and forgot to put the tape on readonly. The file was on fsf position 23, but the tape had 27 files. I know that file 23 is lost but since I pressed ctrl+c to cancel the tar command, can I still hope to somehow recover the other tar files? I tried fsf past file 23 and all I get is input/output error.

I was thinking maybe do a dump from file 23 using dd and then get this file and use a signature file recovery tool, like photorec. Is this doable?

Comment: I tried using dd with bs=10240 and it stops right after the point in the tape where I pressed ctrl+c from the tar. Is there a way to just read everything until the end of the tape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is completely device specific, depending on the drive hardware and its associated driver.

When botching tape operations (like interrupting a write) you can easily make a non-readable symbol or even a non-readable stretch on the tape. You've already shown that your driver is not capable of reading past the junk your aborted write left since `mt fsf` just issues an ioctl that asks the driver to just skip to the next EOF mark. Since the driver returns EIO you are likely not going to be able to get it to do any better.

Depending on how vital this tape is to you, the next step is probably sending it to a forensic recovery firm skilled in the art of magtapes. Your data is probably there but most drivers don't know how to cope with the marker defect you introduced.

Comment: If I go to file 23 and build a small tar just to insert an EOF, could this allow the drive to be able to skip past 23? In the meanwhile, I going to test another device to read the tape. As soon as I can, I´ll post the specs of the first device for the sake of completeness, since it´s device specific. So dd is the right tool for the job, just not for my device, right?

Comment: Nopey. dd cannot do anything that the device driver doesn't afford and I've never seen any commercial drivers that do what you are hoping (writing an EOF at a specific location despite preceding junk). This is why people who have had too much experience with magtape are so glad we don't see much of it any longer. With paper-tape (which I never used) you could at least see the defects and fix them with a knife and glue, if only magtape were as forgiving.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the reads starting from the other end of the tape:

```
#! /bin/sh
set -e
TAPE=/dev/... # change me, you must use a non-rewinding device.
export TAPE

# Wind to the end of the tape.
mt eod

# Rewind to the beginning of the last file and then list it.
# It's possible I misunderstood the way end-of-data is signaled
# on the tape and if so perhaps this command should be mt bsfm 2,
# in which case you can just combine this with the loop below.
# For context here you can look at the entry for MT_ST_TWO_FM
# in "man st".
mt bsfm 1
tar -f "$TAPE" -t

# We just read a file so we're  going to need to rewind over it
# and then rewind more to get to the beginning of the previous file.
# I forget whether tar leaves the tape at EOF or just after it. I'm
# assuming here just after, but if it leaves the tape at the EOF
# mark, the 2 on the next line would need to be a 1.
while mt bsfm 2 
do
  tar -f "$TAPE" -t
done
```

That would **list** the contents of all the tar archives we can reach from the end of the tape.   Of course there are also archives at the beginning of the tape but you can list those much more easily:

```
while tar -f "$TAPE" -t
do
  true
done
```

The `mt eod` operation asks the driver to wind to the end of the tape by winding past filemarks.  This should work fine if all you did to interrupt the tape write was kill the tar process with SIGINT (Ctrl-C).  From the SCSI tape driver's point of view this just looks like the user-space program closed the file descriptor, so there should be an EOF mark at that spot, but no actual "damage".

However, if there is something else going on here and/or the above approach doesn't work, you may be able to get a different result by asking the tape driver to space to the end-of-media by sending a SCSI command to the tape drive asking it to do that.  That's not the same as the default behaviour (which is that the tape driver by forward spacing over files, to that it can keep track of the current file number (to report in operations like `mt status` and `mt tell`).  To configure this you would use the `MT_ST_FAST_EOM` ioctl.  I don't know how to set that from the command line, you may need to create a small C program, a bit like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/mtio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  (void)argc;
  (void)argv;
  struct mtop mt_cmd;
  mt_cmd.mt_op = MTSETDRVBUFFER;
  mt_cmd.mt_count = MT_ST_BOOLEANS | MT_ST_FAST_MTEOM;
  if (0 != ioctl(1, MTIOCTOP, &mt_cmd)) {
    perror("MTSETDRVBUFFER on stdout");
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

To save on boiler-plate, I assumed that the tape device is already open on stdout for this program (i.e. you run it like this: `./myprog >"$TAPE"`).

I have not tested that code, please use with caution.   If it tells your kids they can have a puppy, don't blame me.  You can use another C program to reverse the setting, but you could equally well simply reboot the machine if continued service availability isn't a concern.